# Speed up mouse cursor speed

Tags: c#, winapi, mouse

In C#, how can I set the mouse cursor speed above 20? Anything above 20 is ignored and set to 20 anyway.. Would capturing velocity of the mouse pointer and adding it in real-time to the movement of the mouse be possible? If so, how?

This is the code I used to set the mouse speed:

```
public const UInt32 SPI_SETMOUSESPEED = 0x0071;

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern Boolean SystemParametersInfo(
        UInt32 uiAction, 
        UInt32 uiParam, 
        UInt32 pvParam,
        UInt32 fWinIni);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SystemParametersInfo(
            SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 
            0, 
            uint.Parse(args[0]), 
            0);
    }
```

Comment: Your text asks two completely different questions.

Comment: I Edited it. Meant it as a possible suggestion though I still have no idea if or how it could be done.